# lua love2d, not spawning in bullets

Tags: lua, love2d

Ive been working on a game, but for some reason the "bullet" im trying to spawn in just wont!?

This is my 'Main'

```
require "scripts.player"
require "scripts.bullet"

function love.load()
bulletShoot = love.graphics.newImage("pics/bullet.png")
playerPic = love.graphics.newImage("pics/player.png")
background = love.graphics.newImage("pics/background.jpg")
player_load()
bullet.load()
end

function love.update(dt)
player_update(dt)
bullet.update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
love.graphics.draw(background, 0, 0)
bullet.draw()
player_draw()
end
```

My 'Player' where I try to call it

```
function player_shoot(dt)
playerShootTimer = playerShootTimer * dt
if(playerShootTimer > playerShootTimerLim) then
    if love.keyboard.isDown("space")then
        bullet.spawn(playerX + (playerWidth / 2) - (bullet.width / 2), playerY)
    end
  end
end

function player_update(dt)
player_move(dt)
player_boundary()
player_shoot(dt)
end
```

and my 'Bullet' where I try to draw and spawn it

```
function bullet.spawn(x,y)
table.insert(bullet, {x = x, y = y})
end

function bullet.draw()
for i,v in ipairs(bullet) do
    love.graphics.draw(bulletShoot, v.x, v.y, bullet.width, bullet.height)
end
end
```

things ive tried
- ive changed the bullet to a filled square instead of calling the png
- ive copied and pasted the bullet class from an existing(working) game ive made

none of these things have been useful.
Any help is useful, thank you!

Comment: the provided code only contains a few function definitions.. please provide a minimal executable example.

Comment: I'm not too keen on Lua internals, but in `bullet.spawn` you add a table with `x` and `y` members set, but in `bullet.draw` you loop through every member of `bullet` and attempt to draw using those `x` and `y` variables. Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that loop also include the functions `bullet.spawn` and `bullet.draw`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that in `player_shoot` you are *multiplying* `playerShootTimer` by `dt` instead of *adding* it.

```
playerShootTimer = playerShootTimer + dt
```

I'm assuming `playerShootTimer` starts at zero. Then you have if it becomes greater than `playerShootTimerLim` and space is pressed, spawn a bullet. You will also need to reset the `playerShootTimer` back to zero after spawning a bullet if you want to allow the player to shoot multiple times.

```
if love.keyboard.isDown("space")then
    bullet.spawn(playerX + (playerWidth / 2) - (bullet.width / 2), playerY)
    playerShootTimer = 0
end
```